# Porque mis rutas no funcionan?

Tags: laravel

estoy aprendiendo a crear rutas en Laravel, quiero entenderlas bien para mis endpoints, pero incluso siguiendo la documentación en mis rutas siempre sale error 404, el código de mi `web.php` es el siguiente:

```
<?php

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

  Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function(){

    Route::get('login', function () {
        return 'Hola desde login';
    });

    Route::get('register', function () {
        return 'Hola desde register';
    });
});
```

Para que las rutas sean así `<direccion>/user/login` o `<direccion>/user/register`, no sé si es que hay declarar un middleware en la lista de rutas en el archivo `RouterServiceProvider.php` o en algún otro, o si no es la forma correcta de hacer grupos con rutas
El programa es prácticamente recién creado, no hay controladores ni nada por el estilo, pues solo quiero ver que si llegue a la ruta

Comment: Prueba limpiar la cache `php artisan optimize:clear` y volviendo a cargar

Comment: Justo era eso, gracias..!!